# A rotating ring on frictionless plane gets its centripetal force from?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

A ring is rotating on a frictionless plane. From where does it get its centripetal force to keep on rotating?

Answer (score 2):

Any segment of the ring suffers tension because of the rotation. The tension is what gives the necessary centripetal force.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't require any force (or more properly torque) to keep rotating: continuing to rotate unless acted on by an unbalanced torque is what spinning things do.

This is the same basic confusion as Aristotle belief that things tend to come to a stop if you don't push on them. It appears to be true on Earth because friction and drag are ubiquitous so nothing is actually free of forces when you stop pushing on them.

But your question posits a lack of friction and that means that using your experience on Earth as a guide is faulty: all the systems you have experience with have disipative forces at work.

---

Aside: Even when the continued application of force is necessary (as on Earthly approximations to the system in your question) it isn't centripetal (that is 'directed toward the center') but rather a tangential couple. The centripetal force is what keeps the bits from flying apart and that is the mechanical tension in the ring (a result of the ring being a solid rather than a fluid).

Comment: This answer reads a bit like "No force is required [for A], and when it is, it's not centripetal force. Oh, and centripetal force is required [for B]." which might sound confusing. I guess OP needs to give more details in the question for us to know whether his question refers to A or B. This answer is good if OP knows that a centripetal force is always required for any circular motion but doesn't understand that it doesn't mean an *external* force to a spinning body, but I don't know if that's OP's problem.

Comment: @JiK There are several misconceptions implied by the text text of the question, as well as a possible disagreement between the question in the title and the question in the body. The question I answered is *"From where does it get its centripetal force to keep on rotating?"* And the answer is "no force is required under the situation you specify". Of course, any attempt to approximate those condition on Earth is bound to failure and an external agent will be needed, but that won't be a 'centripetal force' it will be a torque.

Comment: A centripetal force on the parts bits of the ring is required to keep the ring together, otherwise they would fly straight, destroying the ring. I think it's entirely possible OP referred to that.